# ActionBarSherlock onCreateDialog() error: "must override or implement a supertype method"

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-dialog

I'm using ActionBarSherlock, and running into a problem, I think related to imports (?).

I'm trying to use onCreateDialog() and onPrepareDialog() to present a custom dialog box from a SherlockListFragment.  For example, the onCreateDialog looks something like this:

```
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    AlertDialog alert = null;

    switch (id) {
    case DIALOG_CASE_1:

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

        builder.setMessage(question)
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // do stuff
                }
             })
             .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                     dialog.cancel();
                 }
              });

          alert = builder.create();
          break;

    default:
        alert = null;
    }

    return alert;
}
```

This approach works fine from a SherlockActivity, but I'm getting an error with SherlockListFragment:

```
The method onCreateDialog(int) of type MyFragment must override or implement a supertype method
```

I get a similar error for onPrepareDialog().  As indicated above, MyFragment extends SherlockListFragment.

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions to resolve this error.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These APIs are deprecated, you're supposed to be using DialogFragments: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html

Comment: Thanks, Flavio.  Yes, I know they're deprecated, but I haven't yet switched over yet and wanted to make this work.  Any suggestions?

Comment: I bit the bullet, and switched to DialogFragments rather than debugging for deprecated code.  Thanks.

Comment: hiii @gcl1 do you know how to create multiple dialogs  by using onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) using DialogFragment like the same we do by using onCreateDialog(int id) as before.

Comment: Sorry @Abhijit, I'm not clear if your message was a comment or a question.  Also note that I solved my original problem by switching to DialogFragments.